# Ember.JS Integration Testing Issues with andThen and click helpers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, integration-testing

I'm getting odd results with Ember's test helpers `andThen` and `click`.  According to Ember's [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-helpers/):

> the `andThen` helper will wait for all preceding asynchronous helpers
>   to complete prior to progressing forward.

However, I'm finding this doesn't always seem to be the case.  In the example below, there are 3 `console.debug` statements.  I would expect them to be logged in the order A -> B -> C.  Yet I consistently get this order: A -> C -> B.  I can only get the expected ABC order when I use only 1 of the two click helpers. There are no event listeners (actions) associated with the `<div>` element referenced within the click helpers.

Can anyone explain this unexpected behavior?  Is there an error in my usage of the helpers?  Or a bug with Ember's testing framework?

```
andThen(function() {
    console.debug('mark A');

    click('div:first'); // with just 1 click helper, debug order is ABC
    click('div:first'); // with this second click helper, debug order is ACB

    andThen(function() {
        console.debug('mark B');
    });
});

andThen(function() {
    console.debug('mark C');
});
```

---

**Edit**:

Based on the answer given by Kingpin2k, I ended up pursuing the following solution to get at the testing style I was seeking.

First, I created an asynchronous test helper named `next`.  Second, I replaced all the `andThen` helpers in my code with the custom `next` helpers.  This allowed my code to run in the order I was expecting.

```
// test-helper.js
Ember.Test.registerAsyncHelper('next', function(app, fn) {
    fn();
});

// my-integration-test.js
next(function() {
    console.debug('mark A');

    click('div:first');
    click('div:first');

    next(function() {
        console.debug('mark B');
    });
});

next(function() {
    console.debug('mark C');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`andThen` is just syntactical sugar for `lastPromiseEmberSawCreated.then`  so really it looks like this:

```
lastPromiseEmberSawCreated.then(function(){
  console.debug('mark A');

    click('div:first'); // with just 1 click helper, debug order is ABC
    click('div:first'); // with this second click helper, debug order is ACB

  nextLastPromiseEmberSawCreated.then(function() {
        console.debug('mark B');
    });
});

// the promise won't have changed in between these two `andThen` calls 
// because Ember had no cpu time, and you didn't make any additional calls 

lastPromiseEmberSawCreated.then(function(){
    console.debug('mark C');
});
```

Comment: Your explanation is different than what I understood based on the documentation at http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-helpers/#toc_wait-helpers. But your explanation makes sense and led me to the solution I described in the edited post.

Comment: It's a little hidden, but it's implied in this statement `Note andThen has a single argument of the function that contains the code to execute after the other test helpers have finished.`, but this statement `The andThen helper will wait for all preceding asynchronous helpers to complete prior to progressing forward.` is misleading, really you need to read them together for an accurate statement.  It really means the code inserted won't execute until the current global promise completes, but it will continue on with the code outside of the andThen.

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer a reason to use `andThen` in tests, which hopefully will reduce confusion. You could rewrite your example (assuming this is in a function marked `async`:

```
console.debug('mark A');

await click('div:first');
await click('div:first');

console.debug('mark B');

console.debug('mark C');
```

The statements execute in order.